# How to escape "/" character in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to bring Wordpress data to Google Sheets. 
The script below worked for almost all columns but I can't bring the emails and if I try to scape the "-" my script won't run.

```
function getPage(offset,per_page) {
  // gets posts in chunks of per_page
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  // used for error messages
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  var options = {
      'method': 'get',
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    }
  var apiHost = 'https://domain.com.br/wp-json';   // set to your own domain
  url = apiHost + '/acf/v3/cadastros?per_page='+per_page+'&offset='+offset;
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response)
    // loop through the map and output to sheet
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     row=offset+i+2;  // set the row to make sure it is below header and takes into account the paging
     ss.getRange('A'+row).setValue(data[i].id);
     ss.getRange('B'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.contato);
     ss.getRange('C'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.e-mail); //this line is breaking everything I've tried to use "\", put quotes but nothing seems to work
     ss.getRange('D'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.telefone);
     ss.getRange('E'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.cnpj);
     ss.getRange('F'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.endereco);
     ss.getRange('G'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.principais_produtos);
     ss.getRange('H'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.volume_disponivel);
     ss.getRange('I'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.estoque_disponivel);
     ss.getRange('J'+row).setValue(data[i].acf.aceite);

  }
    return data.length;
  } catch(error) {
    var result = ui.alert( error.toString());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy will be to replace `data[i].acf.e-mail` with `data[i]['acf']['e-mail']`